# Mongo Find one set of field in nested object

Tags: arrays, mongodb

i have a follwing structure in mongo db

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e8d3323fe482ef368b4567"),
    "productId" : "poe10001134",
    "batchdetails" : [ 
        {
            "batchidId" : "BD0166",
            "batchno" : "BbfN-1444-SBRPX"
         },
        {
            "batchidId" : "BD0167",
            "batchno" : "Bff-8444-kfkff"
         },
         {
            "batchidId" : "BD01447",
            "batchno" : "Bff-8415-kfkff"
         }
]
}
```

i want to achieve following result

"productId" : "poe10001134"

"batchno" : "Bff-8415-kfkff"

when i execute following query

```
db.getCollection('table').findOne( {"batchdetails.batchidId" : "BD01447"},{productId:1,"batchidId.batchno":1})
```

it returns all the batch no

"productId" : "poe10001134"

"batchno" : "BbfN-1444-SBRPX"

"batchno" : "Bff-8444-kfkff"

"batchno" : "Bff-8415-kfkff"

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
db.getCollection('table').findOne( {"batchdetails.batchidId" : "BD01447"},
    {productId:1,"batchidId.batchno.$":1})
```

The `$` in the projection contains the index of the `batchno` array element that was matched in the query.